# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ..." throwed when trying to make unit tests in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make unit tests for my project, but I am having issues:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 34, in testFailure
    raise self._exception
ImportError: Failed to import test module: data_normailizer_list9_test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/bao/aeris/amp-datasweep/src/test/data_normailizer_list9_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from src.main import data_normalizer
  File "/home/bao/aeris/amp-datasweep/src/main/data_normalizer.py", line 6, in <module>
    import logger_util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'logger_util'
```

. I am using PyCharm as my IDE.

My directories look like this:

```
project_folder
  + src
    + main
      - data_normalizer.py
      - logger_util.py
      - __init__.py (JUST AN EMPTY FILE)
    + test
      - data_normailizer_list9_test.py
      - __init__.py (JUST AN EMPTY FILE)
```

My `data_normailizer_list9_test.py` file looks like this:

```
from src.main import data_normalizer
import unittest

class DataNormalizerList9Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test(self):
        #DO STUFF
```

My `data_normalizer.py`:

```
import json

import logger_util (THIS LINE THROW ERROR)
import math

def a_func:
    #DO STUFF
    #return a result
```

However, I keep getting the error at the under test file `data_normalizer.py`:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'logger_util'
```

Edit: `logger_util.py` is in the same place with `data_normalizer.py`. And the main function works, means there is no issue with business code, just an issue with unit test code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution myself:

```
import os, sys, inspect

currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
maindir = os.path.join(parentdir, 'main')
sys.path.insert(0, maindir)

import data_normalizer
import unittest
```

Also mark main, test as source directory on PyCharm

Comment: You could also include them in the `pythonpath`.

Comment: could you guide me? I'm completely new to python . I'm using PyCharm

Comment: In essence it's the same as your approach but done in terminal. `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/modules/` appends `modules` folder to your enviorement variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to verify module name and location: Double-check that the module 'logger_util' exists and is located in the expected directory. Make sure the file is named 'logger_util.py' and is present in the same directory as 'data_normalizer.py' then add the project directory to the Python path not sure if PyCharm will automatically include the project directory in the Python path. Maybe you should add it manually Use a relative import: Since 'logger_util' and 'data_normalizer' are in the same directory, you can use a relative import statement in your 'data_normalizer.py' file:
***from.import logger_util***

Comment: Hi bro, thanks for your answer. I edited my post, kindly recheck it